# Como testar aplicação Web Server CoffeeScript usando cmd do windows?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, coffeescript

Estou tentando testar [este projeto feito angular](https://github.com/ThomasBurleson/angularjs-Quizzler).

Já realizei a instalação do angular,bower, grunt e do coffescript.

Consegui chegar ate a etapa da inicialização Web Server onde o autor diz :

> Use Terminal to start the CoffeeScript, built-in Quizzler Web Server
>   web server; provided in the tools directory:
>
> ```
> cd ./client
> coffee ../tools/webserver/run.coffee
> ```

Mas quando tento acessar `http://localhost:8000/index.html` no navegador ele aparece o seguinte erro no console :

> must provide a proper url as target

Veja na imagem os comandos executados :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]